# How to output strong typed variables in JSON

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, json

I am using PDO to output SQL results to JSON. The problem is that everything is a string, but I would like integers and booleans not to be string. Is there a way to do this?

This is what I am doing:

```
$db = getConnection();
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM chapters');  
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$db = null;
echo json_encode($results);
```

And this is what it give me:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Book1","pages":"123",active:"\u0001"}]
```

But I would it to output this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Book1","pages":123,active:true}]
```

The columns in MySQL columns are indeed ints and bits. How to I output the right types so I don't have to parse these on the client-side?

Comment: mysql don't have boolean type. only nulls you may have

Comment: you could go through the array $results and replace all \u0000 and \u0001 with what you want - in php, before encoding it.

Comment: @MightyPork FYI: `$results` is not an array, it's an object. It's still possible to iterate through the properties though.

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad really?

Comment: If you're using `PHP version >= 5.3.3` you could try `json_encode($results, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)`.